# How to load P/E ratio for S&P 500 ETFs

Tags: r, quantmod

Using `quantmod` I can load P/E ratios of company stocks, but not ETFs even though they can be viewed on Yahoo financial webpage. For example, for `SPY` it can be veiwed here http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SPY&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uhb2. However, the command in R does not produce anything:

```
getQuote("SPY", what = yahooQF("P/E Ratio"))
             Trade Time P/E Ratio
SPY 2016-05-17 04:00:00       N/A
```

It works fine for stocks though:

```
getQuote("MSFT", what = yahooQF("P/E Ratio"))
              Trade Time P/E Ratio
MSFT 2016-05-17 04:00:00     38.94
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Yahoo, it looks like the P/E ratio for ETFs is only calculated on a periodic basis. You can see this if you go directly to the [page for SPY](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=spy&ql=1), which says that the P/E ratio is as of 4/30/16.

Yahoo likely does this on a periodic basis because the holdings of an ETF may change on a daily basis, and depending on the ETF type may or may not be published daily. If they are published, they are published on the fund's site, so it would be difficult for Yahoo to go to each fund's site, update the ratio of holdings, and then calculate a P/E ratio each day.

Since you can get other information from Yahoo for ETFs, one can infer that `getQuote` does not return the P/E ratio because it's outdated for the ETF.

Comment: I see, that must be it. So would there be any way to automate the process?

Comment: Sure - you would need to scrape the fund's site to get the asset allocation, then go and grab the price and earnings for each asset in the fund, and calculate the P/E ratio from there.